# Does Akamai GTM support GRPC server health check?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-tag-manager, health-check, akamai

I have set up a GCP GLB behind which I have GRPC service as a backend, I can only hit the back with ip:port to create a connection to the GRPC backend. So i want to be able to set up a health check in Akamai GTM to test the service for auto failover between regions. Akamai GTM health checks support only http/REST client but not sure if they do grpc as well so anyone has ever set up something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Liveness tests supported by GTM are documented on techdocs: https://techdocs.akamai.com/gtm/docs/managing-liveness-tests

Currently:

- DNS (port 53)
- DoH - DNS over HTTPS (port 443)
- DoT - DNS over TLS (port 853)
- FTP (port 21)
- HTTP (the default; port 80)
- HTTPS (port 443)
- POP (port 110)
- POPS (port 995)
- SMTP (port 25)
- SMTPS (port 465)
- TCP (port default not specified)
- TCPS (port default not specified)

There is no out of the box GRPC option but maybe you can achieve what you want with HTTPS or TCP?